# Whats new in Microsoft.Owin.* 2.1.0-rc1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

Asp.Net Identity v1 has some really cool technology but as is evident by the queries on this forum lots of difficulty in understanding how to integrate this security model with an existing database model.

Is there any documentation or examples of what we can expect in the currently public v2.1.0rc1 versions of the libraries?

Comment: Your question has multiple questions mixed up. AspNet Identity V1 has Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.* packages. Its still in 2.0.0-alpha1 stage stage of develoment.

Comment: Microsoft.Owin.* pacakages are in 2.1.0-rc1 development stage. They are useful for external authentication purposes and some can be used in combination to local auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity specific changes will show up in 2.0.0-alpha1 identity release(formerly 1.1-alpha1, and are already available on the nightly feed), but there aren't any major changes that will show up for identity from the 2.1.0-rc1 owin bits themselves.

Comment: ok i see so are there any notes.examples for the nightly Identity changes?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question on what's new in Microsoft.Owin.* 2.1.0-rc1 :

1. Google OAuth2 middleware  is being added to Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google package.
2. Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles - A new package containing OWIN middleware to serve static files.